# PrestaShop 1.7.4 override admin template

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm developing my own module.

How to override template located in: 
\admin\themes\default\template\controllers\customers\helpers\view\view.tpl ?

I created file in my module folder: 
\modules\my_module_name\override\controllers\admin\templates\customers\helpers\view\view.tpl .

When I install my module, folder \override\controllers\admin\templates\  is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Prestashop DevDocs](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/overrides/#theme-template-override) we can not override templates directly by putting admin template files in `override` folder in our module.

> Overriding a theme from a module is NOT possible, and never will. If
>   you need this, you have to look instead at the parent/child theme
>   feature.

There one thing that you can do is you can put `template` files in `override` folder and copy these files on module `install/reset` and remove these files on module `uninstall`. To achieve this we can call our `function` to `copy` override and `remove` override in `install()` and `uninstall()` function that is provided by default in Prestashop.

You need to do below mentioned step in you module to override admin templates.

1) Add list of template file(s) that needs to be overridden in you modules `__construct()` method

***__construct() Method***

```
public function __construct()
{
    // ..... your other code here ....

    // list of template(s) file that needs to be override
    $this->admin_tpl_overrides = array(
        implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array('override', 'controllers', 'admin', 'templates', 'customers', 'helpers', 'view', 'view.tpl'))
    );
}
```

2) Add `view.tpl` file that you want to override in modules override folder on below path. Make sure have done your changes in this file.

`modules\{YOUR_MODULE_NAME}\override\controllers\admin\templates\customers\helpers\view`

3) Modify `install()` and `uninstall()` methods in your modules class file.

***Install Method***

```
public function install()
{
    $addAdminTplOverrides = $this->_addAdminTplOverrides();

    return parent::install() && $addAdminTplOverrides /** Other hook you need to register + Method you need to call on install **/;
}
```

***uninstall() Method***

```
public function uninstall()
{
    $removeAdminTplOverrides = $this->_removeAdminTplOverrides();

    return parent::uninstall() && $removeAdminTplOverrides /** Other hook you need to un-register + Method you need to call on uninstall **/;
}
```

4) Called `_addAdminTplOverrides()` and `_removeAdminTplOverrides()` method in `install()` and `uninstall()` respectively; add these functions just after uninstall method.

```
private function _addAdminTplOverrides() 
{
    $module_override_path = $this->getLocalPath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $result = true;
    foreach ($this->admin_tpl_overrides as $admin_tpl_path) {
        $override_file_path = $module_override_path.$admin_tpl_path;
        $dest_override_file_path = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$admin_tpl_path;

        if(file_exists($override_file_path)) {
            if (!copy($override_file_path, $dest_override_file_path)) {
                $result &= false;
            }
        } else {
            $result &= false;
        }
    }        
    return $result;
}

private function _removeAdminTplOverrides() 
{
    $module_override_path = $this->getLocalPath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $result = true;
    foreach ($this->admin_tpl_overrides as $admin_tpl_path) {
        $dest_override_file_path = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$admin_tpl_path;            
        if(file_exists($dest_override_file_path)) {
            if (!unlink($dest_override_file_path)) {
                $result &= false;
            }
        }
    }        
    return $result;
}
```

5) Now `install/reset` your module; you can see admin template is overridden now.

***Complete code from step 1 to 5 here***

```
public function __construct()
{
    // ..... your other code here ....

    // list of template(s) file that needs to be override
    $this->admin_tpl_overrides = array(
        implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array('override', 'controllers', 'admin', 'templates', 'customers', 'helpers', 'view', 'view.tpl'))
    );
}

public function install()
{
    $addAdminTplOverrides = $this->_addAdminTplOverrides();

    return parent::install() && $addAdminTplOverrides /** Other hook you need to register + Method you need to call on install **/;
}

public function uninstall()
{
    $removeAdminTplOverrides = $this->_removeAdminTplOverrides();

    return parent::uninstall() && $removeAdminTplOverrides /** Other hook you need to un-register + Method you need to call on uninstall **/;
}

private function _addAdminTplOverrides() 
{
    $module_override_path = $this->getLocalPath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $result = true;
    foreach ($this->admin_tpl_overrides as $admin_tpl_path) {
        $override_file_path = $module_override_path.$admin_tpl_path;
        $dest_override_file_path = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$admin_tpl_path;

        if(file_exists($override_file_path)) {
            if (!copy($override_file_path, $dest_override_file_path)) {
                $result &= false;
            }
        } else {
            $result &= false;
        }
    }        
    return $result;
}

private function _removeAdminTplOverrides() 
{
    $module_override_path = $this->getLocalPath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $result = true;
    foreach ($this->admin_tpl_overrides as $admin_tpl_path) {
        $dest_override_file_path = _PS_ROOT_DIR_.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$admin_tpl_path;            
        if(file_exists($dest_override_file_path)) {
            if (!unlink($dest_override_file_path)) {
                $result &= false;
            }
        }
    }        
    return $result;
}
```

Hope these will be helpful to you!

Answer (score 1):

Template was at **<admin_folder>/themes/default/template/controllers/orders/helpers/list/list_header.tpl**

Override at **override/controllers/admin/templates/orders/helpers/list/list_header.tpl**

May be it will help somebody :)
https://addons-modules.com/en/content/94-how-to-use-theme-override-of-prestashop-back-office-admin-pages-

[image]